# Faisablity of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Be the following equation $Ax=b$ where $A$ and $b$ have entries over $\mathbb{N}$. $A$ is a full rank matrix of size say $m \times n$.

1) How to check if the equation admits a strictly positive solution in $\mathbb{(R^{*+})^{m}}$

2) How to find at least one such solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Let $A^{\prime}$ be a matrix with $n$ rows from $A$. We choose the same $n$ rows from $b$ to get $b^{\prime}$ and solve $A^{\prime}x = b^{\prime}$. Note if $m = n$, then $A^{\prime} = A$ and $b^{\prime} = b$.

Since $A$ is of full rank, it is a one-to-one transformation. It follows that $A^{\prime}$ is also a one-to-one transformation. So the solution of $x$ will be unique. We use Cramer's rule to calculate each component of $x$.

Let $d = det(A^{\prime})$. Now $x_{i} = \frac{det(A^{\prime}_{i})}{d}$, where $A^{\prime}_{i}$ takes the $i$th column of $A^{\prime}$ and replaces it with $b^{\prime}$.

Comment: Thank you for yout answer.
Actually I have more unknowns than equations, in other word $n>m$. How would you from $A'$? A work around would be adding $n-m$ independent rows to $A$ to form $A'$. But this will add ne constraints and may be no solution will be possible...

Comment: Your best bet then would be to row-reduce and go from there. You could have infinitely many solutions though.

Comment: Actually I want to be sure of the existence of a solution and then find only one.
What do you mean by row reduce? row-reduce $x$ and $b$?

Comment: Row-reduce $A$ to get it into reduced echelon form: https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/linearsystems/linearsystems.pdf

Comment: Yeah but will not lead necessarily to strictly positive solution...?